# Set a min unit displayed price for variable products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I'm building a webshop in WooCommerce for selling Medical Gloves. They are being sold by unit, by box or by palet. When you buy by box or palet, you get a lower unit price.

I've been playing around for a while but I can't seem to get the configuration just how I want.

Let me give an example first.
Product A:
Price per unit: €1,90.
Price per unit when buying a box: €1,76 (120 units).
Price per unit when buying a pallet: €1,63 (2880 units).

What i would like is the following:
- on the archive page it should show: From €1,63.
- on the product page, users can select buy per unit / box / pallet.
- depending on the selection, the price should calculate automatically. So if user chooses 1 pallet, the price should be 2880*1,63=4694,40. Or if user chooses 2 pallets, the price should be (2880*1,63)*2

I've been experimenting with minimum maximum quantities. I've entered the unit prices in the variation tabs and added minimum quantities and steps. For example the pallet minimum of 2880 units and 2880 steps. Basically it works but... I think it would be confusing for the client if they see 2880 as a quantity in the order form, instead of just 1 pallet.

Other possibility is if I just directly add the total prices to the variation tabs, so €4694,40 for a pallet. This also works but... on the archive page it shows From €1,90. So they don't see directly they can get a unit from 1,63 if they buy per pallet.

I thought about using Measurement Price Calculator but those plugins only work with measurements like volume and weight, not quantity.

Anyone has experience and a possible solution with this issue? 
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use variable products and set 3 variations for each product:

- per unit
- per box
- per pallet

1) In backend: for variable products only, we add a custom setting field, for the "Min unit price" to be displayed.

[image]

2) In frontend: for variable products only, we display that custom "Min unit price" in shop, archives and single product pages.

[image]

The code:

```
// Backend: Add and display a custom field for variable products
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_custom_product_general_field');
function add_custom_product_general_field()
{
    global $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group hide_if_simple hide_if_external">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id'          => '_min_unit_price',
        'label'       => __('Min Unit price', 'woocommerce') ,
        'placeholder' => '',
        'description' => __('Enter the minimum unit price here.', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
    ));

    echo '</div>';
}

// Backend: Save the custom field value for variable products
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_product_general_field');
function save_custom_product_general_field($post_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['_min_unit_price'])){
        $min_unit_price = sanitize_text_field($_POST['_min_unit_price']);
        // Cleaning the min unit price for float numbers in PHP
        $min_unit_price = str_replace(array(',', ' '), array('.',''), $min_unit_price);
        // Save
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_min_unit_price', $min_unit_price);
    }
}

// Frontend: Display the min price with "From" prefix label for variable products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_min_unit_variable_price_html', 30, 2 );
function custom_min_unit_variable_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $min_unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_min_unit_price', true );

    if( $min_unit_price > 0 ){
        $min_price_html = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $min_unit_price ) ) );
        $price = sprintf( __( 'From %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), $min_price_html );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Wauw yes that seems to work. the only problem is I display prices with a "," for decimals and a "." as thousand separator. If I add the price 1,63 it displays 1.00. If I change this in my settings I see it works and shows 1.63. Is there a workaround for this so I can keep the comma for decimals?

Comment: Yes I understand, but in the WooCommerce general settings I use a comma for decimals. In the Min Unit price label on the product edit page, I enter 1,63 and on the product page it shows 1,00. So it seems this code only works if you've set a point for decimals in the woo settings.